# QPrinter Is there a function to write the source of the print on the sheet

Tags: qt

I'm currently making an application that can print the content of my widget. That is done. But now, I would like to be able to write at the bottom of each page the source and/or copy rights. For example : when you print a page from internet, there's always the url at the bottom of the page.

So I would like to do basically something like that. I looked in the doc but I didn't see anything to do it quickly. Because if there's nothing I will have to handcode it and I would prefer to avoid that

Thanks!!!

Comment: I thought that maybe I could use a `QPainter`and try to write some text at the bottom of my file...but it doesn't seem to work because it erases what was on the page...it doesn't simply add the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [page footer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_footer).  There's apparently no built-in support for it but this link may help:

http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/is_it_possible_to_set_a_header_and_footer_when_printing_a_qtextdocument